# CreateProcess Won't Start

Tags: winapi

I'm getting error code 2, Can't find the file. But i've tried with full path and without.
I've had no luck getting the process to start and i don't know what my mistake is, can somebody point it out?

This is the full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <psapi.h>
#include "shlwapi.h"

#define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2;

void Debug(char* path[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    char* p = path[0];
    char* args = path[1];

    int dwProcess = CreateProcess((LPCWSTR)p, (LPWSTR)args, NULL, NULL, false, DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (!dwProcess)
    {
        DWORD dwLastErrorCode = GetLastError();
        printf("Error: %d", dwLastErrorCode);
    }

    DEBUG_EVENT debug_event = {0};
    DWORD dwContinueStatus  = DBG_CONTINUE;
    DWORD dwResume          = DBG_EXCEPTION_HANDLED;

    while (!WaitForDebugEvent(&debug_event, INFINITE))
    {
        switch(debug_event.dwDebugEventCode)
        {
            case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            {
                EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO& exception = debug_event.u.Exception;

                if (exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == 0x0EEDFADE && exception.dwFirstChance)
                    dwContinueStatus = dwResume;
            }
        }
        ContinueDebugEvent(debug_event.dwProcessId, debug_event.dwThreadId, dwContinueStatus);
    }
}

int main(char* argv[])
{
    char* p[2] = { "Notepad.exe", "args" };
    Debug(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try performing error checking? That's the first thing you should do. After you do that, you might be able to realize which arguments are causing trouble and why it's a bad idea to do whatever you can to compile code. Here's a start: *If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*

Comment: Need to provide absolute path for notepad.exe?

Comment: @billz, You shouldn't have to for notepad.exe. It's typically in a directory covered by PATH.

Comment: yeah, I just tried it from console and it worked without absolute path

Comment: I've tried with the full path too, no luck

Comment: Follow chris steps, check errors ...

Comment: read the document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx as well

Comment: "Can't start my process" is meaningless. What exactly does that mean? What does `CreateProcess` return? What does `GetLastError` tell you? There is absolutely no question here, because you haven't asked one, and haven't made any effort to even explain the problem, much less to solve it.

Comment: I get Error code 2, File not Found, sorry if i was unclear.

Comment: @Dean, I hinted on something in the last part of my actual comment (before the copied text from the CreateProcess doc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int dwProcess = CreateProcess((LPCWSTR)p, (LPWSTR)args,
```

↑ Don't cast `char*` to `wchar_t*`.

Remove all C casts and be much happier. :-)

As a practical matter, use wide strings (`wchar_t`-based) for dealing with the Windows API.

A simple way to get wide character program arguments with Visual C++ (although it's specific to this compiler) is to use `wmain` instead of standard `main`.

---

**Amendment** I forgot this is SO. So what actually *happens* when you cast a `char*` to `wchar_t*`?

Well in Windows each `wchar_t` is 2 bytes. This means that each pair of successive `char` values in your strings will be treated as one `wchar_t` value, *if* the thing doesn't crash. It might crash because the null-termination of a wide string is 2 zero bytes, while your `char` strings only guarantee a single zero byte, so from the point of view of the `CreateProcess` code your strings may continue indefinitely…

In short, don't cast.

Each cast says to the compiler, “Shut up, compiler, cause I really do understand what I'm doing, I'm not doing this by mistake!”

And if one does not actually know what one's about, then the effect is to silence the tool that keep on trying to help you avoid catastrophe.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a full path instead of just `notepad.exe`. Taken from [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to
>   execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial
>   name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to
>   complete the specification. **The function will not use the search path**.
>   This parameter must include the file name extension; no default
>   extension is assumed.

If you want `notepad.exe` to also open that file, you need to repeat the `notepad` part for `lpCommandLine`. From the same page:

> If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL, the
>   null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the
>   module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by
>   lpCommandLine specifies the command line. The new process can use
>   GetCommandLine to retrieve the entire command line. **Console processes
>   written in C can use the argc and argv arguments to parse the command
>   line. Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally
>   repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.**

Comment: It only looks in `PATH` for `lpCommandLine`, not for `lpApplicationName`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Ansi buffers for your parameter data, but you are calling the Unicode version of `CreateProcess()` instead of the Ansi version.  Get rid of your type casts (the compiler would have warned you of your mistake had you nt used them) and then call `CreateProcessA()` directly:

```
//CreateProcess((LPCWSTR)p, (LPWSTR)args, ...);
CreateProcessA(p, args, ...);
```